# How to set message caption using Facebook Messenger SDK for iOS

Tags: objective-c, facebook, sdk, caption, messenger

I need to set a caption when I share a picture (QR code) from my app integrated with Facebook Messenger.
There is metadata NSString field but I don't see a way how to use it. Did anyone solve that problem?

> metadata field You can see that we're passing options to the share
>   method. This contains two fields we want to send back to Messenger:
>   metadata and contextOverride.
>
> The metadata field takes a NSString and is optional. It can be used to
>   give information about the content being shared. For example, you can
>   store a serialized JSON string. This is useful during replies as this
>   data is passed back to your app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/ios#bp_using_metadata

Answer (score 2):

The metadata is meant for you, as a developer, to use. For example, when a user creates an image from your app you can attach metadata to it, at that point. This metadata is sent, in the background, together with the image to the recipient. When they decide to reply, using your app, you will receive the metadata there.

You can use this, for example, if in your app somebody selected a category to get the image. When you pass in this category in the metadata (which is up to you to format, but JSON is convenient), you get this metadata/JOSN in your app when the recipient replies. You can read the category and load the images on that category already.

The metadata **does not** set a caption to your image. Actually, there is no integrated way to add a caption to your images.

I would advise to generate the QR-code part of the image *and* the caption in your app. The image that you post to the Messenger API is thus a combination of the QR-code and a textual caption above or below it. Does that make sense?

ps: about the credible source; I'm a developer support engineer at Facebook :)

Comment: Good answer. Just to clarify: QRCodes (or any barcode) is just data embedded into an image. Many images allow some amount of metadata, to be used by developers. Consumers of those images can use the metadata (to, for example, show map coordinates where a photo was taken) but it won't affect the image, which is a bitmap. But you can take the image of the QRCode, embed it into a larger bitmap, add a caption overlay, and upload this new image that you've generated with the code and the bitmap.

Comment: I though the same way with QR code. Here is my demo from a hackathon with an example with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4MUNyNFYlE Most common question was how to click the link and the second was how to read qr code from the same screen.

Comment: @Roemer Do you have any idea how pinterest add a caption to image, in invite via messenger.